# Data Augmentation avoid RAM problem

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, data-augmentation

I have a dataset (`imgs`) which is a list of numpy.ndarray: images of dimension (200, 200, 3).
When I try to augment it with imgaug library I always occur in RAM error, all available RAM is used when the dataset `imgs` is bigger than 1500 elements. I need to augment 33k elements.

I could try to divide the dataset in batches and feed the `augmentation` function 1 batch at a time but I don't know how to do.

Here is the code:

```
def augmentation(images):
    #1. --------- Flipping Augmentation ---------
    flipping_augmentation = iaa.Fliplr(1)
    flipped_images = flipping_augmentation(images=images)

    #2. --------- Rotating Left Augmentation ---------
    rotate_left_augmentation = iaa.Affine(translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)},
                                          rotate=(-30, -5),
                                          scale=(0.5, 1.5))
    rotate_left_images = rotate_left_augmentation(images=images)

    #3. --------- Rotating Right Augmentation ---------
    rotate_right_augmentation = iaa.Affine(translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)},
                                           rotate=(5, 30),
                                           scale=(0.5, 1.5))
    rotate_right_images = rotate_right_augmentation(images=images)

    tot_imgs = images + flipped_images + rotate_left_images + rotate_right_images
    return tot_imgs


imgs = load_dataset()
res = augmentation(imgs)
```

Comment: Currently you are performing the different augmentation steps seperately and storing the intermediate results, meaning that they all get stored in memory. Try using the [`imgaug.Sequential`](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/overview/meta.html?highlight=sequential#sequential) class (or the [`imgaug.SomeOf`](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/overview/meta.html?highlight=sequential#sequential) depending on how you want to apply the augmentations) to combine the augmentations and apply them at once to prevent storing the intermediate results.

Comment: Because I want to increase my dataset of a factor of 4. For each image i want to have the image + image_flipped + image_rotate_left + image_rotate_right. I would like to train my model on the same data(x4) but I don't know if it's a good way of feeding the NN. 
With the imgaug.Sequential object I obtain a different dataset for each epoch and I don't know if it's preferable to train the model on the same data for more epochs .

Comment: How much RAM do you have available? If you want to hold all images multiplied by four in memory it might simply be that you do have sufficient RAM on your machine to do so.

Comment: I am using Google Colab and I have about 27GB of RAM. The total amount of RAM I should need is 1.5x4 = 6GB but still I have the RAM error.
Anyway if I want to try the imgaug.Sequential can I put it inside my NN structure ?

Comment: If you want to use the `Sequential` class just use it in the same way as you are currently using the transformations, that is by augmenting the images and supplying those to your neural network instead of incorporating it in the neural network.